# In IEEE 754 and JavaScript, how is 0 and -0 represented differently?

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

I am curious as to, even `0 === -0`, but `1/0` and `1/-0` give different results.  So we can probably assume that `0` and `-0` are represented differently in IEEE 754.  How are they represented?

**Update:** so far, I can find some info on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

and it seems that there are IEEE 754-1985 and IEEE 754-2008, and one form might be, in binary:

```
0 00000000 00000000000000000000000  as positive 0
1 00000000 00000000000000000000000  as negative 0
```

(the above is 32 bit, with the left most bit the sign bit, then to the right, 8 bit as exponent, and then 23 bit as the significand).  But I can't find the different between the 1985 and 2008 version.

Comment: [Wikpiedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) did not help?

Comment: of the 71kb wikipedia article, I searched for `-0` but didn't find anything.  I don't think for the fact that something can be found on the Internet or Wikipedia, it can't be a question on SO

Answer (score 1):

See:

[IEEE 754-1985 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

[IEEE 754-2008 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

and for the changes see [the "IEEE 754 revision" page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision).

Both 1985 and 2008 versions are using **signed zero**.
They are represented as:

> sign = 0 for positive zero, 1 for negative zero.
>
> biased exponent = 0.
>
> fraction = 0.

(exactly as you wrote in your question)

Edit: in both 1985 and 2008 version, 1/0 = **infinity** while 1/-0 = **negative infinity**.

Comment: I've added the third link for you (but it won't show up until my edit is peer reviewed).

Comment: where do you get the number 1865?

Comment: It is called a typo =) (sorry)